# Links don't work after hitting back button in iPhone5

Tags: jquery-mobile

This seems to only be happening on iPhone 5 for me. I've tried it on my Nexus 4 and I can't replicate it.

When I navigate through the site, and hit the back button (either the browser back or the back button on the page), links no longer work. If I hit the browser's refresh button, then everything works again.

I read somewhere, where this code could help, but it didn't:

```
$(document).on("pagehide", "div[data-role=page]", function (event) {
    $(event.target).remove();
});
```

Has anyone ran into this? I'm using jquery-1.9.1.min.js and jquery.mobile-1.3.0.min.js

Just to reclarify, I have tried this in other versions of iOS and it works. In fact, I just tried it int he iPhone 5.1 simulator in xCode and I've had no problems. It works on Android. It's just the iPhone 6.0 simulator and newer.

I've noticed that the links only stop working on the home page. On the home page, I have a slideshow using jquery-tools. On the other pages there isn't a slide show and i can navigate through the site, use the back button, and the links still work.

**Update 1:** Ok, so I removed the scroller and it's still broken. But still only the homepage.

**Update 2:** Ok, so it definitely seems to be the way the link's are. I removed step by step all the content from the main body copy including slideshows and you tube videos. nothing changed.

But I did find out that links in the menu, and footer, both still work and I can go back/forth between the home page and sub pages and everything works. But as soon as I click a link from within the body and go back to the home page then everything stops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, figured it out. The internal body links had target="_blank"  on the anchors. That was screwing it up. When those were removed, problem solved. Go figure!